# A (spoofed?) trusted device has logged in from an unrecognized location

Tags: google-account, security

Recently my Google account was hacked.

I have 2-factor authentication turned on. 2-factor authentication was not required for the hacker to gain access to my account, nor did the hacker trigger Google's suspicious activity monitor. This is because the log in was enacted from a "trusted device" or so it seems.

However, the log-in was done from a location which I never visited and from a device name I do not know.

See attached image:

[image]

The hacker managed to gain access to my bank account and other various accounts without triggering any of their 2-factor authentication blocks.

One more note:

When the attack occurred, the device that I brought with me to Israel and then back to New York, as far as I can tell, was turned off, so it is not likely that the hacker gained remote access to that device.. but then again.. maybe they did?

Any idea what happened to me and how I can make sure it doesn't happen again?

(They also managed to get access to my bank account, add a wire recipient (a process I usually have to verify over the phone with a human), and make a successful wire transfer, but let's stick to the Google question)

For the record, I have changed all of my passwords and ran a virus scan that came out without results, but since the 2-factor authentication was enabled on literally all of my services, there wasn't much I could do beyond that.

Comment: What devices do you usually use to log in to Google? Have any of these been out of your sight/possession during or shortly before this incident? That includes border authorities. What additional software did you install in that period (especially apps); what possible malicious links could you have clicked on?

Comment: Do you use a VPN or something similar?

Comment: @JanDoggen I can't think of anything.. The weirdest thing is the device's name...

Comment: @Rubén nope... I don't